# Is it possible to get Sound Menu integration for cmus?

Tags: indicator-sound, cmus

I really like the terminal media player [`cmus`](https://cmus.github.io/).

I would like to have Ubuntu Sound Menu integration with cmus, so I can skip tracks, see the album art, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Cmus** does not natively support playback control via D-Bus/MPRIS. To my knowledge there is no third party plugin providing MPRIS control of cmus, at least I couldn't find any. Therefore we can not integrate it to the Indicator Sound menu the way we use to other MPRIS-capable players.

As an alternative to the sound menu you may want to have a look at some projects that [allow remote cmus control](https://github.com/cmus/cmus/wiki/remote-control) via a web-interface or an Android app, or aid in [displaying player status](https://github.com/cmus/cmus/wiki/status-display-programs).

Answer (score 0):

The latest [cmus pre-release (2.8)](https://github.com/cmus/cmus/releases/tag/v2.8.0-rc0) now supports MPRIS.
You can use and install `playerctl` to control its behavior.
F.e.

```
playerctl next
playerctl prev
playerctl pause
```